How to fix blurry edges on JS canvas
I am working on a canvas and I want it to be responsive (look same on different screen sizes), resizable (look same when browser window resizes and resize properly), size-adjustable (user can enter canvas output size) and look sharp (no blurry edges of shapes).
The code I have below satisfies all other criteria but it shows edges of shapes blurry. For example, the top and left edges of the rectangle in the drawing below are blurry, whereas right and bottom edges are sharp.


var cnv = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
var wrp = document.getElementById("wrp");

// ar (aspect ratio), size (user can enter different values - the canvas size to save as output)
var ar = 0.8
var size = 2000
var width, height;

var scale = size / ((innerWidth < innerHeight * ar) ? innerWidth : innerHeight * ar);

function draw() {
  setup();

  ctx.fillStyle = "#D4CAA3";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height); // background
  ctx.fillStyle = "#A15837";
  ctx.fillRect(200, 200, 200, 200); // position can change
}

function setup() {
  const PR = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

  let w = innerWidth,
    h = innerHeight;

  // accounts for portrait and landscape orientations
  width = (w < h * ar) ? w : h * ar;
  height = (w < h * ar) ? w / ar : h;

  wrp.style.width = width + "px";
  wrp.style.height = height + "px";

  cnv.width = Math.ceil(size * PR);
  cnv.height = Math.ceil(size / ar * PR);

  ctx.scale(scale, scale);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", draw, false);
draw();
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #222;
  margin: 0
}

#wrp {
  margin: 0 auto
}

canvas {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
<div id="wrp">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>



The above code is a result of endless search on here and other resources, but I still couldn't get rid of the blurry edges. Any ideas how to fix that?
P.S. Adding 0.5px to coordinates or width/height do not always work, so, I am looking for other approaches if possible.
My last resort is to draw each shape 3-4 times, which makes them appear sharp but this is not ideal code and performance wise, and will avoid if I can find another solution.
EDIT: Edited code seems not to be drawing the rectangle, here's a working live example on my site: https://www.yenren.art/cnv/ where you can see blur. Firefox and Chrome shows blur on opposite edges.
Thanks!

Yes just like you found out ctx.scale( will do that to you... your best alternative is to not hardcode the ctx.fillRect(200, 200, 200, 200) instead resize your canvas to as big as it can then draw that with variable depending on your canvas width and height

Thanks Helder, when I draw variable depending on width like width * 0.1 the position and size of the rectangle changes when I resize the browser, since width measures the resized size of the window. When I draw variable depending on cnv.width which is constant, there's still blur.

Here is how I would tackle this:

no wrp.style.width or wrp.style.height
no ctx.scale(...)
resize the canvas as big as the window (or any other size)
then everything we draw must be relative to the dimensions of the canvas

Here is an example:

drawing two squares relative to the center
squares are one fourth the dimensions of the canvas



var cnv = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d")


function draw() {
  setup();
  square = Math.min(cnv.width/4, cnv.height/4)

  ctx.fillStyle = "#D4CAA3";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height); 

  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(cnv.width/2, cnv.height/2, square, square); 

  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(cnv.width/2-square, cnv.height/2-square, square, square); 
}

function setup() {
  cnv.width = window.innerWidth
  cnv.height = window.innerHeight
}

window.addEventListener("resize", draw, false);
draw();
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #222;
  margin: 0
}
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>



you can test the resize in full page mode to see how the squares stay at the center an proportional to the window dimensions

Some additional info from our comments:
If the user wants a size but your browser is a different, you will get a distortion (blur or pixelation) no matter what we try. An option  is to show the user something without distortions using the true window dimensions, and if user wants to download then you can redraw a canvas on a background job with the user requested size.
Some useful links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Background_Tasks_API#example
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL


The reason I have scale is because size is a variable which comes from the user input. So that the canvas can be saved in different sizes, say at 1000px width, 2000px width etc. based on user input (comes as URL parameter). And aspect ratio is also an important thing, which should work the same both on landscape and portrait browser windows. These are what complicate it for me.

@yenren You have a conflict If the user wants a size but your browser is a different, you will get a distortion (blur or pixelation) no matter what you try... what you can do is show the user something without distortions but using the true window dimension, and if user wants to download then you can redraw a canvas on a background job with the user requested size

Thank you very much for the suggestion. Now that I think on it, it sounds more like what I need, instead of forcing things to look how I want. Can you suggest a working example/tutorial for such a setup if you know? Thanks!

@yenren I updated the question with some more detail, if the answer solves your issue don't forget to accept it
